# Google Cloud Messaging: how to ask for google play services availability with GoogleApiAvailability Class

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging, google-play-services, availability

i want to work with google cloud messaging for my android app. it is said that you need to check for google play services availability first. but i don't know how to implement this. just searched through GoogleApiAvailability Class. Problem is i don't understand how to set up check and use method .getErrorDialog() in my case. It is said requestCode is "The requestCode given when calling startActivityForResult". but how to use it?

```
public void onResume() {
    GoogleApiAvailability availability = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance();

    int checkForGPS = availability.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if(checkForGPS != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        availability.getErrorDialog(this, checkForGPS, requestCode);
    }
    super.onResume();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

```
private boolean checkPlayServices() {
    int resultCode = GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(this);
    if (resultCode != ConnectionResult.SUCCESS) {
        if (GooglePlayServicesUtil.isUserRecoverableError(resultCode)) {
            GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(resultCode, this, PLAY_SERVICES_RESOLUTION_REQUEST).show();
        } else {
            Log.e(TAG, "This device is not supported.");
            finish();
        }
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: but it is said GooglePlayServicesUtil.isGooglePlayServicesAvailiable() is deprecated

Comment: But still you can use it.